# Add Custom TagHelpers in ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I've followed the ASP.NET Core documentation to the letter and spent a significant amount of time trawling stack overflow trying to implement a simple custom TagHelper with no success.

Would anyone be able to advise on any gotcha's or known bugs?

Application Properties:

```
AssemblyName: AmpWeb
Target Framework .NET Core 2.1
```

NuGet Packages

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2
```

Enviroment

```
OS: Windows 7 (x64)
SDK: Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.1.302 (x64)
IDE: Visual Studio 2017 Professional 15.7.4
```

TagHelpers/EmailTagHelper.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace AmpWeb.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "email")]
    public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "a";    // Replaces <email> with <a> tag
        }
    }
}
```

Views/_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AmpWeb
```

Index.cshtml

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<email>WHY</email>
```

Output

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<email>WHY</email>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a subtle issue but an important one.  The issue is this line of code `[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "email")]`

If you remove it it should work by using your `<email>WHY</email>` markup.  You could also replace it with `[HtmlTargetElement("email")]` but it's not actually even needed in this case because the framework can infer that info from the name of the class `EmailTagHelper`.

By including `[HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "email")]` you are saying that you want the tag helper invoked via an attribute on any tag.  So invoking it would be something like `<div email></div>` or `<span email></span>` for example.